# Support two forms of sequences in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm trying to support two different structures for a specific element.

This is the example i am trying to allow:

```
<wrapper>
    <example>
       <a>str</a>
       <b>str</b>
       <cs>
          <c>str</c>
          <c>str</c>
          <c>str</c>
       </cs>
    </example>
    <example>
       <a>str</a>
       <e>str</e>
       <cs>
          <c>str</c>
          <c>str</c>
          <d>str</d>
       </cs>
    </example>
</wrapper>
```

Clearly the structure is different, although it contains some similar sections.

Rules:

- a must appear in both types
- b must appear on the first type, e must appear in the second
- cs must appear in both types
- cs can contain as many c as we want, but we can add another d on the second type

I was trying to write the following xsd:

```
        <xs:element name="wrapper">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="example">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:choice maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="a" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="b" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="cs">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:sequence>
                                                <xs:element name="c" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                                            </xs:sequence>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                </xs:sequence>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="a" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="e" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="cs">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:sequence>
                                                <xs:element name="c" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                                                <xs:element name="d" maxOccurs="1" type="xs:string"/>
                                            </xs:sequence>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:choice>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
```

However, when i use it for validation, the result is an exception:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Error for type '#AnonType_example'.
>   Multiple elements with name 'cs', with different types, appear in the
>   model group.

What's the best way to implement this kind of validation? I was trying extracting each sequence under a group and referencing it but the result was the same.

**EDIT:**
Tried to take the common a out but there still a complaint about cs:

```
<xs:element name="wrapper">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="example">
                    <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="a" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string"/>
                                <xs:choice maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="b" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string"/>
                                        <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="cs">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:sequence>
                                                    <xs:element name="c" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                                                </xs:sequence>
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="e" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string"/>
                                        <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="cs">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:sequence>
                                                    <xs:element name="c" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                                                    <xs:element name="d" maxOccurs="1" type="xs:string"/>
                                                </xs:sequence>
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:choice>
                            </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

> Error for type '#AnonType_examplewrapper'. Multiple elements with name 'cs', with different types, appear in the model group.

Answer (score 0):

Your content model needs to be unambiguous. So, for example, instead of offering a choice between `(abc)` and `(aecd)`, you should rewrite it as a sequence that starts with `a` and continues with a choice, that is `(a(bc|ecd))`. If there is a choice, the first element name encountered must enable the system to decide which branch of the choice to take.

Edited since you seem to need it spelled out:

```
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="a" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="b" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="cs"/>
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="e" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="cs"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Not sure which part of my response you didn't understand but I've spelled it out in more detail for you.

Comment: tried your suggestion but cs is still ambiguous. Can i somehow solve this? the described structure is not ambiguous IMO since the definition is quite strict.

Comment: The structure as I have written it is not ambiguous, and compiles just fine. You must have varied it in some way, e.g. by making b or e optional.